Does every triangle with sides $a,b,c$ and inradius $r$ satisfy $\frac{2}{3} \le \frac{a}{a+r} + \frac{b}{b+r} - \frac{c}{c+r} \le \frac{4}{3} $?
Let $a,b,c$ be any the side of a triangle in random order and $r$ be its inradius. Experimental evidences show that
$$
\frac{2}{3} \le \frac{a}{a+r} + \frac{b}{b+r} - \frac{c}{c+r} \le \frac{4}{3} 
$$
Both the upper and the lower bounds occur in the limiting case a degenerate triangle when the length two sides is approaches the circum-diameter and the third side approaches zero.
Can this be proved?

Have you got geometric descriptions for the limiting cases? For an equilateral triangle with sidelength $1$  (or any sidelength at all, I suppose), I guess the expression yields $\frac 1{1+\sqrt 3/6}=\frac 6{6+\sqrt 3}\approx 0.775990762$, right?

And is your notation well defined?  How are you singling out $c$?  Is it the longest side or something?

@lulu I have updated the post to answers to your queries about the limiting case. Also $c$ is not necessarily the longest or the shortest side. $a,b,c$ are in random order.

Of course, there is a closed formula for the inradius given the three sides.  Herron tells you the area $\Delta$ and then $r=\frac {\Delta}{s}$ where, of course, $s$ is the semiperimeter.  The resulting formula is a bit messy, but is it that bad?

@lulu With Heron's formula and the facts that $r = \Delta / s$ mine got really cumbersome. I think there must be some elegant proof since the bounds are simple ratios

Can you explain what you mean by "degenerate triangle when the length two sides is approaches the circum-diameter and the third side approaches zero"? In particular, if $ a = b = 1 $ and $ c \rightarrow 0$, then $ r \approx c/2$. I don't see a side can approach the circum-diameter.

Extend triangle (every side extend $+r$ and for so butterfly triangles. Apply Thalès and Al-Kashi or compute directly as proposed in previous  comment. Now, with what I have, I see only ways paved with calculus.

@CalvinLin Here is what I meant. Assume the circumradius is $1$ i.e the circumdiameter is $2$. When does the lower bound approach $2/3$ or the upper bound approach $4/3$? This happens when the length of two sides approach $2$ and the third side approach $0$.

My point is that " when the length of two sides approach 2
and the third side approach 0", then the circumradius is not 1. Can you demonstrate otherwise? EG $ r = \triangle/s \approx 0 / 1$ so it's very close to 0 like I stated.

OK. Here is an actual triangle inscribed in a circle of radius $1$. Taking $a = 1.9999963218544616$, $b = 1.999996289037038$, $c = 0.000017073585456246912$, the value of the expression in the question is $1.3333234375743999$. As you can see the value of $a,b$ is close to $2$ which is the circumdiameter.
